# Angular 11 Nested Form doesn't trigger NgSubmit by Enter keyup

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I have two different forms, which i want to keep in different components and submit each form by ngSubmit event. Parent form triggered normally, but child form doesn't trigger **ngSubmit** when i create two o more inputs.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-khbymb?file=src/app/nested-form/child-inputs/child-inputs.component.html

Parent form and ts component:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="flex">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input formControlName="input" matInput required />
  </mat-form-field>
  <app-child-inputs (formValidity)="isChildFormValid = $event"></app-child-inputs>
</form>
<button
  (click)="apply()"
  [disabled]="!form.valid || !isChildFormValid"
  mat-flat-button
  color="primary">
  Apply
</button>
<button (click)="cancel()" type="button" mat-stroked-button color="primary">
  Cancel
</button>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from '../toast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nested-form',
  templateUrl: './nested-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class NestedFormComponent {
  isChildFormValid: boolean;

  form = new FormGroup({
    input: new FormControl(''),
    select: new FormControl(''),
  });

  constructor(private toast: ToastService) {}

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid && this.isChildFormValid) {
      this.apply();
    }
  }

  apply() {
    this.toast.apply();
  }

  cancel() {
    this.toast.cancel();
  }
}
```

Child form and ts component:

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" class="flex">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Login</mat-label>
    <input  matInput
              formControlName="initialLogin"
              type="text"
              required>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
    <input  matInput
            [type]="passwordHide ? 'password' : 'text'"
            formControlName="initialPassword"
            required>
    <mat-icon matSuffix
              class="pointer"
              type="button"
              [matTooltip]="'Show/Hide password'"
              (click)="passwordHide = !passwordHide">
      {{passwordHide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}
    </mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

```js
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastService } from '../../toast.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-inputs',
  templateUrl: './child-inputs.component.html',
  styleUrls: [],
})
export class ChildInputsComponent {
  @Output() formValidity = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  form = new FormGroup({
    initialLogin: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    initialPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });

  constructor(private toast: ToastService) {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() =>
      this.formValidity.emit(this.form.valid)
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.apply();
  }

  apply() {
    this.toast.apply();
  }
}
```

I don't want to use keyup.enter or any similar events. Forms should be in different components.
Adding invisible button with type submit help, but i hope there is more obvious solution.

Comment: There isn't. Forms work by adding an `button type="submit"`, so that when you press enter, the button is clicked for you. It's either that or a `keyup.enter` event, as you said.

Comment: Your Apply button is of `type="submit"`. That's the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type) for the button `type` property. Check if the apply button is disabled due to the form validity.

Comment: @MGX, sad. Strange then why the parent form work without that button.

Comment: @TETSUKER because by default, a button in a form is of type submit